# Any fast way to check if two doubles has the same sign?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

Any fast way to check if two doubles have the same sign? Assume the two doubles cannot be 0.

Comment: In what language? How much do you care about portability?

Comment: I prefer c# language

Comment: Ok. I think that rules out direct access to the sign bit. In C, if you get your hands dirty and depend on the details of the fp implementation, you could do very cheap bitwise comparisons.

Comment: Can either of the doubles be -0? Or NaN?

Answer (score 11):

**Potential solutions:**

1. `a*b > 0`: One floating-point multiply and one comparison.
2. `(a>0) == (b>0)`: Three comparisons.
3. `Math.Sign(a) == Math.Sign(b)`: Two function calls and one comparison.

**Speed comparison:**

It's about what you'd expect (see experimental setup at the bottom):

1. `a*b > 0`: 0.42 ± 0.02s
2. `(a>0) == (b>0)`: 0.49 ± 0.01s
3. `Math.Sign(a) == Math.Sign(b)`: 1.11 ± 0.9s

**Important notes:**

As noted by [greybeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789665/greybeard) in the comments, method 1 is susceptible to problems if the values multiply to something smaller than `Double.Epsilon`. Unless you can guarantee that the multiple is always larger than this, you should probably go with method 2.

---

**Experimental setup:**

The following code was run 16 times on http://rextester.com/.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double a = 1e-273;
    double b = a;
    bool equiv = false;
    for(int i=0; i<100000000; ++i) {
        equiv = THE_COMPARISON;
        b += a;
    }
    //Your code goes here
    Console.WriteLine(equiv);
}
```

Comment: What about two positives that overflow back to a negative number?

Comment: @cricket_007 Doubles? They overflow to `inf`.

Comment: Is that not possible? I mean, I know doubles have lots of bits, but still, it's a limited space in memory

Comment: Risks NaN/Exceptions.

Comment: @greybeard Does it? `-inf` and `inf` compare correctly, and you can't get `NaN` on a non-zero multiply...

Comment: What about +/- 2^-123?

Comment: `(NaN > 0) == (-1 > 0)`, but -1 and NaN do not have the same sign.

Comment: @PaulHankin Whether `NaN`s are possible is a good question, but even if so the issue is moot. Since `NaN`s do not have a usable sign, you would have to check for `NaN` for any of these methods.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and fastest way for [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) I know of is just using `XOR` on the **MSB** bits of both numbers. Here is a small **C#** example (note the inlining to avoid the function overhead):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private unsafe static bool fpu_cmpsign(double a, double b)
{
    byte* aa;
    byte* bb;
    aa = (byte*)(&a); // points to the a as 8bit integral type
    bb = (byte*)(&b); // points to the b as 8bit integral type
    return ((aa[7] ^ bb[7]) & 128) != 128;
}
```

Here result of `+/-` numbers combinations:

```
a b result
- - 1
- + 0
+ - 0
+ + 1
```

The idea is simple. The sign is stored in the highest bit (**MSB**) and `XOR` returns `1` for non equal bits so `XOR` the **MSB** of booth numbers together and negate the output. the `[7]` is just accessing highest `BYTE` of the `double` as 8 bit integral type so I can use **CPU ALU** instead **FPU**. If your platform has reversed order of `BYTES` then use `[0]` instead (**MSB**yte first vs. **LSB**yte first).

So what you need is just 3x 8 bit `XOR`s for comparison and negation and 1x 8bit `AND` for extracting sign bit result only.

You can use unions instead of pointers and also use native bit-width for your platform to get best performance.

Comment: I used inlining to avoid the function overhead and compared; it takes about 1.5x as long as `(a>0) == (b>0)` on a release build. It also requires using the `/unsafe` build flag, which reduces portability.

Comment: @Kittsil It depend on compiler, settings, platform and many other things ... As I mentioned I do not code in Python so I am not familiar with optimizations there ... There are many possibilities to try like rewrite pointer access ... use only the predicate, ... use `==`... use 8/16/32/64 bit variables  and more all boils down to how the compiler translates to assembly ...

Comment: @Kittsil btw you added `!=128` instead of direct result  of predicate that is `cmp` ALU operation instead simple bit XOR which can affect performance too

Comment: I added the `!=` (instead of your original `^`) because `C#` doesn't allow conversion from `int` to `bool`. Unfortunately, unlike `C++`, `C#` does not allow as many optimizations; it is intended to be a higher level language (and it's written by Microsoft, so... ;-).

Comment: @Kittsil then may be faster would be `(aa[7] &128) == (bb[7] &128)` which is (`NOT XOR`) basically but also coded as cmp

Comment: Yeah, I tested that one as well. It's within the confidence interval of the first one (which makes sense, as it's two bitwise operators and a comparison).

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
if (copysign(x, y) == x)
```

Comment: @kittsil: It's in C99.

Comment: Can you get this to work? I can't, but if you can include working `C#` code then it's definitely the best solution.